# Why is most probable speed not equal to rms speed for an ideal gas?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, speed

The rms speed of ideal gas is $$\mathit{v_{rms}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{3RT}{M}}.$$
The most probable speed is the speed where $\dfrac{dP(\mathit
{v})}{dv} =0$ where $P(\mathit{v})$ is the probability distibution. Solving for $\mathit{v}$, we get $$ \mathit{v_p} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2RT}{M}}.$$

Now, $$\mathit{v_p} \neq \mathit{v_{rms}}.$$ Why? Why is it so?

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: There are many probability distributions where neither the mean nor the root mean square, nor any other statistically relevant value matches the maximum of the distribution. Nothing in the definition of the root mean square indicates that it should be the maximum of the probability distribution, so what do you mean when you ask "Why?"

Comment: @ACuriousMind: This is the answer! Thanks, sir. Average is the mean . . . So, what is then average meant for ?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I didn't know the fact. Thanks for bringing it forward before my eyes. If I didn't ask 'why', how could I know this important fact? Everything has reason:)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call *"That's the way it is"* a reason, but that's your choice :)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I'll rather take it as a thumb's rule. But really, it seems reasonable, average is just the mean one, the most probable needn't be the average. And the max. speed is also not equal to the most probable one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're used to thinking of "most probable" and "mean value" as the same thing, but it need not be so. It's worth remembering that the "expectation value" of a six sided die is 3.5, but this is not a very probable result. You might object that this is due to discrete effects, but consider this example: you have two identical Gaussians, with width $\sigma$, but they are separated. One has mean value $m_1$ and the other has mean value $m_2 = m_1 + \delta$. If they're identical and we average between them, we get an expectation value of $(m_1 + m_2) /2 = m_1 + \delta/2$. But $\delta$ could be quite large, in particular perhaps the Gaussians are very separated $\delta >> \sigma$. Then the mean value could occur in a point with arbitrarily small probability of actually being selected!

So as a general principle, the most probable value of a distribution and the average value need not be together. Does that help, or would you rather talk more directly about Maxwell-Boltzmann distributions (of atomic velocity)?

Comment: Thanks, sir but really I was talking about the later.

Answer (score 1):

In any probability distribution, there are many ways to find some kind of "average" value, that is, ways to define the "centrality" of the distribution. In discreet distributions you have almost certainly come across mean, median and mode, and perhaps also the different "flavours" of means - arithmetic, geometric, harmonic etc. For continuous distributions we have yet more ways of finding the centrality, e.g. the RMS (normally used for distributions where the random variable can be positive or negative in equal measure) as well as the most probable. Generally these numbers, which are single number representatives of the whole distribution, will be different, although in special cases they can be equal. Here we have a distribution that is certainly not one of these special cases, so it is likely that any two of the chosen measures will be different.

Comment: +1. Thanks, sir, it was brief,concise but an answer to the point. Had it been posted earlier, I would've accepted it:)