# Why is most probable speed not equal to mean speed in case of ideal gas?

Tags: velocity, ideal-gas

since in gausian distribution, the peak of the distribution corresponds to mean value, why isnt most probable speed is equal to ean speeed?

Comment: because speed means the absolute value whose distribution is not Gaussian

Comment: @Bort can u elaborate?

Comment: You are thinking of $P(\vec v))d^3 \vec v$ but should think about $4 \pi v^2 P(v) d v$. The most probable _velocity_ is $0$, but the most probable absolute value of it is obviously is not $0$. Try computing $|x|$ for a standard normal distribution in 1D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is most probable speed not equal to rms speed for an ideal gas?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167013)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is most probable speed not equal to rms speed for an ideal gas?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167013/why-is-most-probable-speed-not-equal-to-rms-speed-for-an-ideal-gas)

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in mathematics (statistics) rather than physics. It is the difference between the mean and the mode of a probability distribution. In any symmetric distribution the mean, mode and median always coincide. In asymmetric or "skewed" distributions they do not necessarily coincide.

The speeds in the kinetic theory of ideal gases are distributed according to the Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution, not the Gaussian Distribution. Unlike the Gaussian Distribution, it is not symmetric. It has a probability density of zero at $v=0$ and has a small but finite probability density at arbitrarily large values of $v$, with a peak in between. The fact that it is not symmetric makes it possible for the mode (most probably value) to differ from the mean value.

Comment: The Maxwell-Boltzmann **velocity distribution** in velocity space  is the product of three Gaussian distributions for each coordinate and thus symmetric. The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of  **speed** (absolute values of the velocities)  is asymmetric. See graph in  answer of @Farcher.

Comment: - I know that your answer concerning the speed distribution is correct (I upvoted it)! I only wanted to point out that there is a difference between the Maxwell-Boltzmann speed and velocity distribution.

Comment: @freecharly : OK. Sorry I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Maxwell Boltzmann distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are in general different for most probability distributions. In fact if you pick a distribution in random, it's much more likely to expect that they will be different rather than happen to be the same.

For example $P(0)=0.99$ and $P(10000)=0.01$. The most probable value is $0$ but the mean is $100$.